# Promise with multiple .then when one then is counting on another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to use implicitly promise-then when accessing `mongodb` through mongoose.
If I have new data on the same date and user, I should remove old data and insert new data.

section A works fine but I think that the all point of `.then` is to prevent indentation like we have in callback methods.
Plus I don't know if I need a `.catch` to every `.then` in this case.

Section B however doesn't work cause the `createdData` returned in  `.then(function(createdData){})` refers to the `DailyData.remove()` method, and returns a totally different object.

A:

```
DailyData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
    .then(function(){
        DailyData.create({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
        .then(function(createdData){
            createdDataGlobal = createdData;
                UpdatedInnerData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
                .then(function(){
                    insertNewInnerData();
                })
                .catch(handleError);
        })
        .catch(handleError);
    })
    .catch(handleError);
```

B:

```
DailyData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
    .then(function(){
        DailyData.create({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser});
    })
    .then(function(createdData){
        createdDataGlobal = createdData;
        UpdatedInnerData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser});
    })
    .then(function(createdData){
        insertNewInnerData();
    })
    .catch(handleError);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unjustified nested `then`s is an antipattern. This is called callback hell; something that promises are supposed to help with but not cause.

Another problem is that promises should always be chained. `DailyData.create(...`) is not returned from `then` callback, this results in improper control flow.

It should be:

```
DailyData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
.then(function(){
    return DailyData.create({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser});
})
.then(function(createdData){
    createdDataGlobal = createdData;
    return UpdatedInnerData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser});
})
.then(function(createdData){
    return insertNewInnerData();
})
.catch(handleError);
```

If `insertNewInnerData()` is asynchronous but doesn't return a promise, it should be modified to return it.

There's no need for multiple `catch`, unless errors have to be handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the promise in your `.then(..)`

Try this:

```
DailyData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
    .then(function(){
        return DailyData.create({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser});
    })
    .then(function(createdData){
        createdDataGlobal = createdData;
        return UpdatedInnerData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser});
    })
    .then(function(createdData){
        insertNewInnerData();
    })
    .catch(handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers already pointed the problem, which is that you were not returning a promise in your `.then(..)`
To make the code a bit more readable, you can use arrow functions. This way you don’t need to explicitly return:

```
DailyData.remove({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})
.then(() => DailyData.create({date: getCurrentDate(), owner: currUser})).then(() => ...)
```